# How to a add dot menu items inside BindableLayout.ItemTemplate/Listview in Xamarin?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am trying to add a three-dot menu like feature inside BindableLayout. I tried the popup page using Rg.Plugins.Popup. The problem with this was the popup position. I have an image for 3 dot menu with Command inside TapGestureRecognizer. I tried getting the current coordinates and pup page but getting the coordinates of items inside listview/BindableLayout was another thing. SyncFusion seems to have the solution but they are not for free. I tried [this](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/245) but no luck. Can anyone suggest me a better approach or solution with my current pattern?
Here is my [Design Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItqTs.png)

Comment: Xamarin.Forms provides the `SwipeView` control which could help to achieve the context menu function in the `ListView` or `CollectionView`. Check the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#context-menus

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a tooltip to your three dots , I think this link would help
http://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

XF-Material-Library seems to have control for this requirement. I fount this very useful. Here is a link to try:
https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library#cards